# How to give separate styles for multiple simple modal in a single page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using a simple modal written by Eric Martin (simplemodal.com) in my page. I need to give separate styles for different simple modals in a single page. The code is written in such a way that whenever we are calling a

```
$('#myID').modal();
```

Generates a simplemodal-container. I need to alter some of it's own generated styles to my other modal box which is in the same page.

Can some one suggest me what needs to be done?

Thanks

Comment: I have not used this plugin before. But if you look here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options the options `ContainerCss` and `overlayCss` seem to do what you want...

Comment: Read their documentations here:http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/; or you can use external css to override the inline styles the library generates.

Comment: @Godinall: That is fine. But when you are invoking a modal, it is just generating a container div from the modal js which stands with the same name <div id="simplemodalcontainer">/div>. so each time, when we call the $('#myID').modal(), it is generating this same container div, which i am unable to set different styles for different modals. got it what i am saying?

Comment: @steeve yes I know what you mean. If you look at the demo page you will find it is actually using different IDs for various demos. But they do all use the same class name.

Comment: I too have been staring at the demo code but on my page the class names being generated remain the default of class="simplemodal-XXXXX".  They are not taking on the name of the ID used to open the modal.  For instance: using $('#msg_box').modal(); I would expect class="msg_box-XXXXX".  This is what appears to be happening on the demo pages but it's not happening on my actual page.  What am I missing?